# Build a table in Angular+Jade from nested JSON , ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pug

My JSON look something like this:

```
   {
  "contact-info": {
    "phonebook": [
      {
        "name": "John Snow",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "home",
            "number": "1234"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "bastard"
      },
      {
        "name": "Arya Stark",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "cell",
            "number": "234"
          },
          {
            "phone": "work",
            "number": "345"
          },
          {
            "phone": "home",
            "number": "456"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "no one"
      },
      {
        "name": "Theon",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "fax",
            "number": "567"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "Reek"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aemon",
        "phones": [
          {}
        ],
        "nick": "maester"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to build a table using Angular that will look like this:
[image]

So far, with my limited knowledge of Angular, I can print ONLY the first number of every name:

```
tbody
    tr( ng-repeat="person in JSON.contact-info.phonebook")
        td {{person.name}}
        td {{person.phone[0].phone}}
        td {{person.phone[0].number}}
        td {{person.nick}}
```

I run into errors each time I want to create a nested ng-repeat for the phone section. How should that be done?

Thank you

Comment: you have quote missing in `tr( ng-repeat="person in JSON.contact-info.phonebook)`

Comment: Was a typo in here, I do have it in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with one `ng-repeat` you need to do nested repeats, one across people and then across peoples phones.

Problem is that you need to iterate twice and still yield table rows. There are two things that can help you ng-repeat-start ng-repeat-end directives and the fact you can put directives in comments.

```
 tbody
   // ng-repeat-start='person in JSON.JSON.contact-info.phonebook'
   tr(ng-repeat='phone in person.phone')
     td {{ person.name }}
     td {{ phone.phone }}
     td {{ phone.number }}
     td {{ person.nick }}
   // ng-repeat-end
```

You will end up with this markup:

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <!-- ng-repeat-start='person in JSON.JSON.contact-info.phonebook'-->
   <tr ng-repeat="phone in person.phone">
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ phone.phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ phone.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.nick }}</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- ng-repeat-end -->
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Another option would be to transform you original json to one level list and use simple repeat.

```
 var allPhones = []

 _.each(json, (p) =>{ _.each(p.phone, (ph) => allPhones.push({
      name: p.name, 
      phone: ph.phone, 
      number: ph.number, 
      nick: p.nick})
 })
```

And deal with simple ng-repeat on angular side

Comment: I end up with such markup: 
`<!-- ng-repeat-start='person in JSON.JSON.contact-info.phonebook'-->
<!-- ngRepeat: phone in person.phone -->
<!-- ng-repeat-end -->`
and table is empty

Comment: I believe first solution is not possible since comment-based repeater had too many browser specific issues to overcome, I believe this feature was deprecated: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1646#issuecomment-21039443

Comment: you can use rowgroup tag i think

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.items = {
  "contact-info": {
    "phonebook": [
      {
        "name": "John Snow",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "home",
            "number": "1234"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "bastard"
      },
      {
        "name": "Arya Stark",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "cell",
            "number": "234"
          },
          {
            "phone": "work",
            "number": "345"
          },
          {
            "phone": "home",
            "number": "456"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "no one"
      },
      {
        "name": "Theon",
        "phones": [
          {
            "phone": "fax",
            "number": "567"
          }
        ],
        "nick": "Reek"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aemon",
        "phones": [
          {}
        ],
        "nick": "maester"
      }
    ]
  }
}
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>phone</td>
      <td>number</td>
      <td>nick</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody  ng-repeat="(key,value) in items">
       
    <tr ng-repeat="person in value.phonebook">
       <td >{{person.name}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="phone in person.phones">{{phone.phone}}{{phone.number}}</td>
       <td >{{person.nick}}</td>
    </tr>
       
       </tbody>
    </table>
            
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, I ended up with a multiple `tbody` tags within the table.
It does work visually, but if you try to style the table, down the road, you may hit some dead ends
Thank you